# gnuplot: multiplots using multiple lines in each plot and in-line data

Tags: gnuplot, torch

I am trying to call gnuplot from torch in order to plot several things. I am trying to use multiplots (like subplots in matlab), and at the same time plot different curves in the same plots. Furthermore, I'm defining the data in-line, i.e., avoiding writing the data in external files (plot '-').

I've tried plotting several curves with '-' in several ways, with multiplot previous and next, with replot... but any combination messes up the layout in one way or another. Does anybody knows how to do this or can give some hints?

Thanks!

**Update**: Added a small example. Blue and red lines should be plotted in the same plot (top one), while green one should be plotted alone in the bottom one.

Example:

```
gnuplot.figure(1)
gnuplot.raw('set terminal x11 0 position 1200,20 persist')
gnuplot.raw('set multiplot layout 2,1')

gnuplot.raw([[plot '-' lt rgb 'blue'
            0 0
            100 30
            e]])

gnuplot.raw([[plot '-' lt rgb 'red'
            0 30
            100 60
            e]])

gnuplot.raw([[plot '-' lt rgb 'green'
            0 60
            100 90
            e]])

gnuplot.raw('unset multiplot')
```

Comment: Well, in order to be able to help, some sample code of yours would be useful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with torch, but I think your problem is with trying to do three separate plot statements.  In gnuplot, to do multiple curves in the same plot (two in your top plot), you specify them in the same command separated by a comma.  Feeding inline data, this means that you will need to provide one set of data, end it with e, provide another, and then end it with e.

Additionally, you can use `lc` (linecolor) instead of `lt` to set your colors.

In straight gnuplot, you will do this like so:

```
set terminal x11 0 position 1200,20 persist
set multiplot layout 2,1
plot '-' lc rgb 'blue', '-' lc rgb 'red'
0 0
100 30
e
0 30
100 60
e
plot '-' lc rgb 'green'
0 60
100 90
e
unset multiplot
```

[image]

If you want lines, just add `with lines` to all three plot specifications like

```
plot '-' lc rgb 'blue' with lines, '-' lc rgb 'red' with lines
plot '-' lc rgb 'green' with lines
```

or change the default data style with `set style data lines`.

[image]

Comment: @DavidGeronimo You're welcome.  If this was helpful, please consider accepting the answer.  You are not obligated to, but it awards the person posting the answer and yourself a small amount of reputation and marks the question as answered.  You may also upvote any answer that you found particularly helpful - either on your own question or anybody else's.